# Java 1.5 Script Engine

Tags: java, scriptengine

Since Java 1.6 there is this nice Script Engine Manager which let's i.e. execute JavaScript scripts in run time. Is there something similar in functionality in Java 1.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Jakarta BSF](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/) lets you run different scripting languages within the Java framework (prior to Java 6). [Here's](http://jakarta.apache.org/bsf/projects.html) a list of supported languages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is - [Mozilla Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/). Same as with 1.6, actually, you just need to write a bit more integration code yourself.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html) on embedding Rhino into your app.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to run JSR223 on Java 5, at least according to [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javascripting1/#java5).